# How to trigger event when a variable's value is changed after a specified time has elapsed?

Tags: c#

I have a value set using a blazor page using a +/- functionality.

I want a function to be triggered when the value hasn't changed for a set period of time.

Currently I'm trying this:

```cs
public int GoalTemperature
{
    get
    {
        return goalTemperature;
    }
    set
    {
        goalTemperature = value;
        if (CheckIfDesiredTemperatureHasChanged())
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

With the function

```cs
private Boolean CheckIfDesiredTemperatureHasChanged()
{
    int referenceTemp = 0;

    if (GoalTemperature != referenceTemp)
    {
        GoalTemperature = referenceTemp;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't do anything.

I'm very new to C#, and have been looking around everywhere. This is a simple thing in other languages, but I can't get it to work in C#.

Comment: What is the goal of this whole ordeal? What should happen if the timeout is hit / not hit?

Comment: My first idea would be to save the timestamp, when a `set` happens. Then you can compare the actual timestamp to the last one and you don't need timers or sleeping threads or anything. If you actually want to trigger something at the very time the timeout elapses, then it's a different story.

Comment: @Fildor I just don't want a continuous update to be called, but wait a few seconds before a function is triggered. It seemed smarter to wait for a moment and have definitive temperature to be sent than constantly update.

Comment: On a web page, that's something one would usually code on client-side using javascript. You could use a C# timer but I'm not quite sure how it's handled by blazor.

Comment: I'm restricted to C# and Blazor sadly...

Comment: Ah, so it's basically a debounce. In Blazor ... hmm ...

Comment: I have the main button feature in a .razor file and the methods in a .razor.cs file, so it's also possible to look at a C# implementation.